# A-frame Screen space reflections

Tags: mobile, server-side-rendering, webxr

Is there any tutorial or easy way to use screen space reflections in A-frame?. I know there are some way to do it with hsls shaders, but it could take so long for me (i'm an artist, and know about shaders, but just some bases).
The idea is to keep the performance for mobile and if it's posible for VR .

As well, Screen space reflection can create some problems with doble images in VR, is there any way to avoid that? like use just one eye rendered to create the reflections.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code for how to create screen space reflections is posted here
https://www.8thwall.com/8thwall/cubemap-aframe/master/